Someone was helping me to fill my DS160 and mistakenly submitted
Someone in the US helped me to fill my DS160 information and mistakenly submitted the application, will the visa officer be able to see through the ip address that the person who submitted and signed is not the actual visa applicant and is out of the country?

In order to avoid the possibility of a refusal of the application and the consequent knock on your DoS record — which might occur should the visa examiner see that the applicant is not the person who submitted the form — you might consider withdrawing your application before it is further considered. A withdrawal is not a refusal.

IP Geo resolution is not an exact science and I have had occasions before where my IP was resolved to a different region, and even country, than what it really was. Unless there are any other concerns, I doubt anyone would even look. If, however, the application is fraudulent and some investigation starts, then ICE might want to find the actual person who submitted it.

There's nothing stopping you from using a friend's computer. work computer. or a internet cafe etc to fill out the form. Given that a phone and tablet's IP address will change when it swaps between your home internet (via WiFi) and mobile data, I doubt they'll check

I imagine there are plenty of people who submit through US VPNs, so I can't see why a US IP address would look suspicious.

FYI, your social media page is rather more of an issue for “someone in the US” than IP geolocation.
